# Does the population mean differ significantly in calculation from the sample mean after multiplying by 1/n?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, binomial-distribution, population

The expectation of a binomial distribution is given by E(X) = np, where n is the number of trials and p is the probability of each trial. When using a normal distribution to approximate the binomial distribution, the mean of the normal distribution also becomes (or is approximated to) np. But then comes the following, which I read in the textbook *Modern Mathematical Statistics With Applications*:

> When the objective of an investigation is to make an inference about a
> population proportion p, interest will focus on the sample proportion
> of successes P^ = X/n rather than on X itself. Because this proportion
> is just X multiplied by the constant 1/n, the earlier rescaling
> proposition tells us that P^ will also have approximately a normal
> distribution (with mean mu = p and standard deviation sigma =
> sqrt(pq/n)) provided that both np >= 10 and nq >= 10.

There's something I'm not correctly understanding here. So when interested in the population mean, we scale the sample mean by 1 / n. So the mean given by

sample mean = np

becomes

population mean = np * (1/n) = p

Does this not imply that the population mean will be significantly different from the sample mean (which doesn't really make sense)? So for example, imagine that n = 10 and p = 0.5. Then np = 5. But then estimating the population mean, mean = p = 0.5, which implies a 10 fold difference between the sample mean and the population mean. Where am I misunderstanding this? Thank you.

Comment: The sample mean $\bar X_n=(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/n$ has expectation $p$

Comment: The notation is confusing here. The X they are talking about is the number of successes out of n independent trials. So you can think of it as the sum of a bunch of random numbers that are each either 0 or 1 (1 with probability p) Each trial has a mean of p. The mean of X (the sum of n trials) is np. The sample mean of the n 0's and 1's is X/n. This will tend to be close to p (and that is its expected value). The confusing notation is that $X_i$ represents a single trial but $X$ represents the sum of n trials.

Comment: @JohnL That explains it, thank you!